# the query findObjectsInBackground not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i have 3 classes, i need to retrieve data depending on some condition , i use this code :

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "RiderRequest")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.username!)!)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

            if let riderRequests = objects {
                for riderRequest in riderRequests {
                    if let driverUsername = riderRequest["driverResponded"] {


                        let query3 = PFQuery(className: "User")
                        query3.whereKey("username", equalTo: driverUsername)
                        query3.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                            if let driverinfo = objects {
                                for driver in driverinfo {

                                    print("driverobject=\(driver)")
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

but the  className: "User" not working and cant get data from it , always the object is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to retrieve data from the User Class with PFQuery is using the following:

```
let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse User is a special Parse class and requires a different Query constructor.

Update your code to:

```
let query3 = PFUser.query()
```

Comment: very thanks toddg its working now depending your answer, thanks again

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you